# Google Drive Save button Text Editing - Cross Domain iframe edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-drive-api, cross-domain

I am trying to edit a cross domain iframe. specifically I want to change the text that appears in the google drive save button.

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/savetodrive this is what I want to edit.

```
$(".gdrivelink iframe").contents().find(".save-to-drive-text").text('Save to Google Drive');
```

I get this error when trying to run the text change code.

```
DOMException {message: "Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from…92.168.2.27" from accessing a cross-origin frame.", name: "SecurityError", code: 18, stack: "Error: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' proper…ject.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:609:21)", INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1…}code: 18message: "Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "xxxx://192.168.2.27" from accessing a cross-origin frame."name: "SecurityError"stack: "Error: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "192.168.2.27" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
    at Error (native)
    at n.each.contents (192.168.2.27/zm/js/jquery.js:2:26312)
    at Function.n.extend.map (192.168.2.27/zm/js/jquery.js:2:3483)
    at n.fn.(anonymous function) [as contents] (192.168.2.27/zm/js/jquery.js:2:26401)
    at <anonymous>:2:25
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:762:137)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:695:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:609:21)"__proto__: DOMException
```

I have searched for this but I could not find resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible as of severe security problems. Because JavaScript is used a lot for Phishing, each page runs inside a sandbox with only as much rights as it needs. Since an iframe is just a page inside another page, the restriction is applied.

Imagine you have two tabs opened, one is online banking and the other one is "evil". What if the evil site was able to fill in forms inside the banking site and submit these forms via javascript?

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) I would upvote, but I can't since my account doesn't have any rep :( I had thought as much :( I was really hoping someone found a work around. I have found that people on here have gotten pretty crafty in terms of dynamically loaded content from other domains. More likely then not I was seeing something with a direct load to the page, not in an iframe. First world problems I suppose. :(